# Choice of window length in Singular Spectrum Analysis

Tags: r, forecasting, spectral-analysis, singular-matrix

Thanks in advance for your answers, I'm trying to decompose a stock price using the Rssa package provided in R, after millions of trials, I tried to change the window Length and the eigentriples, the error between the forecast and the test series is really High, as definition the Window length should be chosen between 1 and (N/2) which is the half of time series of length (N), if we multiply (N/2) for periodicity we should obtain the optimal separation of the components, my question now is "How I should decide the Window length if stock prices do not have an explicit periodicity or seasonal components?"

Comment: The window is less important than the choice of kernel. Read what Emmanuel Parzen has to say about the Epinechnikov kernel.

Comment: I've never had to choose the kernel in Rssa, what are you referring to?

Comment: That is probably because the Epanechnikov kernel is automatically used.

Comment: oh okay i will read the text then, but actually for the window length have you got some tips to use?